# Pandas. Group by field and merge the values in a single row

Tags: python, pandas

I wanted to know how to group a data frame by a field and then join groups in a single row, giving priority to non-null values.
This is an example in which it is grouped by ID:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) with [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and  [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html):

```
print df.replace('null', '').groupby('id').sum().replace('', 'null')
    A  B     C
id            
1   a  r     s
2   q  d  null
3   w  b  null
```

If type of values `null` is not `string`, use [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
print df.fillna('').groupby('id').sum().replace('', 'null')
    A  B     C
id            
1   a  r     s
2   q  d  null
3   w  b  null
```

Answer (score 1):

Set up

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    [1, 'a', None, None],
    [1, None, 'r', None],
    [1, None, None, 's'],
    [2, None, 'd', None],
    [2, 'q', None, None],
    [3, None, 'b', None],
    [3, 'w', None, None]
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id', 'A', 'B', 'C'])
```

df looks like

```
   id     A     B     C
0   1     a  None  None
1   1  None     r  None
2   1  None  None     s
3   2  None     d  None
4   2     q  None  None
5   3  None     b  None
6   3     w  None  None
```

The Solution

```
df.set_index('id').stack().unstack()
```

Looks like

```
    A  B     C
id            
1   a  r     s
2   q  d  None
3   w  b  None
```